# __curl_rule_01__ declared as an array with a negative size

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode6, objective-c++

I added arm64 support in the build settings of my app now get this error in the curlrules.h,
Here is the code where the error occurs:

```
typedef char
 __curl_rule_01__
 [CurlchkszEQ(long, CURL_SIZEOF_LONG)]; //where the error occurs
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously you need to make sure that `CURL_SIZEOF_LONG` is defined as `sizeof(long)` (or the integer-literal equivalent, probably `8`) wherever it's defined. You're probably trying to `#include` a header that still thinks you're on 32-bit ARM.

The "array with negative size" trick is a very common trick to simulate [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) in C and in C++-pre-2011. Look in the source code for the definition of `CurlchkszEQ` if you want to know how it works in this particular case.

Comment: Thanx for explaining what this code is doing e.g. simulate static_assert